# Есть ли возможность удалить все одинаковые элементы списка в Python

Tags: python, список

Есть ли какой-либо метод в Python, который позволяет удалить разу все одинаковые элементы в списка?

Comment: конвертируйте в set и обратно в List

Comment: Совсем удалить или оставить по одному неповторяющемуся элементу?

Comment: Если есть возможность и так и так сделать,то был бы благодарен оба варианта

Comment: прими ты уже хоть чей то ответ, нелюдь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eсли надо именно удалить:

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
list2 = [i if list1.count(i) > 1 for i in list1]
for i in list1:
    if item in list2:
        list1.delete(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hасчет метода не скажу, можно так:

```py
list1, list2 = [1, 2, 3], []
for item in list1:
    if item not in list2:
        list2.append(item)
```

Или так:

```
list2 = list(set(list1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def f(your_list):
    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(your_list))
```